# Importar datos desde un archivo a mysql

Tags: mysql

tengo un problema por que quiero importar datos de un archivo .txt a una BBDD. Estoy leyendo el manual y lo he conseguido pero de esta forma:

```
use menagerie;

truncate pet;

insert into pet (name,owner,species,sex,birth,death) values 
('gato','carlor','gato','f',NULL,NULL);
```

Osea, que tengo que poner la insert y rellenar manualmente los datos, y yo lo que andaba buscando es tener un archivo así:

```
Esponjoso       harold  gato    F   1993-02-04  
Garras          gwen    gato    metro   1994-03-17  
leucocitaria        harold  perro   F   1989-05-13
```

¿Esto es posible o hay que crear alguna rutina en mysql? Por que los datos yo los exporto en este formato.

Gracias

Hola Rodrigo la sentencia se queda así y funciona:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'/home/carlos/MEGA/APUNTES/MYSQL/LOTES/pet.txt' INTO TABLE pet 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
Query OK, 8 rows affected, 24 warnings (0,29 sec)
Records: 8  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 24
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- Debes de tener esos datos separados por algún identificador; por ejemplo, puede ser un pipe |, que es un caracter que difícilmente encontraremos en alguna cadena de texto, como nombres, direcciones, etc.
Se puede hacer como lo tienes, el problema es cuando ocupes algún espacio, esos datos se recorrerán, por eso es mejor utilizar un separador/identificador.

En el caso de utilizar un .csv, tu identificador predeterminado sería la coma ( ,).

Te adjunto un ejemplo de cómo sería:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C://Users//test//Desktop//nombredetuarchivo.txt'
INTO TABLE nombredetutabla
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' -- este es tu identificador / separador.
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: Hola @Rodrigo, perdona pero no he podido responderte antes. Ya me funciona arriba pongo la select como queda, no necesito 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' -- este es tu identificador / separador.' creo que por que trabajo en ubuntu, a lo mejor en windows si es necesario. Pero bueno me funciona como lo dejo arriba. Gracias